# Reversibility, Entropy and Information in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, conservation-laws, information

I suspect that I harbor some misconceptions about these topics. A first item is that QM processes are time reversible. So, in principle, the entropy must remain constant. (??).
A second item is the link between information and entropy as given by Claude Shannon: if entropy is constant then information is constant too. This is similar to what is often vulgarised when explaining the information paradox for black holes.
A third item confusing me is the 'localization' of information in a process like the collapse of the wave function: if a system is in a superposition of 2 states and it collapses into just one of them, does that imply that there is a transfer of information of 1 bit 'out of the system'? Is it 'carried' away by a foton? Can a kind of "double entry bookkeeping" be defined for information in such cases?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what the question is. Item 1 and 2 are unproblematic (and true as far as we know). Item 3 depends on whether collapse happens "for real" - not all interpretations buy it. Maybe you could reformulate the question to "in quantum mechanical collapse, where does the information go?" (assuming I interpreted it right)

Comment: @AndersSandberg: nice to hear items 1 & 2 validated. The question in item 3 is indeed broad, and asks if information obeys some conservation law in Noether's sense. What's the equivalent symmetry then?

Comment: I don't think Noether implies that all conserved quantities have to be due to Lagrangian symmetries?